# why is GIT for Windows showing different versions in git-bash vs git-gui and cmd.exe?

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I ran **git update-git-for-windows** from windows CMD.EXE. It appears to have run fine. Updated, etc. But...

- In GIT BASH, I enter **GIT VERSION** and get "git VERSION 2.33.0.windows.2"
- From CMD.EXE, I enter **GIT VERSION** and get "git version 2.27.0.windows.1"
- In GIT GUI, the **help > About** shows  "git version 2.27.0.windows.1"

What's wrong? How I do I fix it? Which version do I really have? And if I have both versions, how can I get rid of the old one?

Comment: what do you see when you run 'which git' from cmd?

Comment: If I type "which git" in the cmd window, it simply replies that *'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command...*  If I type "which git" into the Git Bash window, the reply is */mingw64/bin/git*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check the repsective shell path with:

- CMD: `where git`
- bash: `which git`

If you see a different path, you would need to clean your %PATH% Windows environment variable and make sure it reference the new Git installation path.

Comment: Thanks Von. I didn't know the WHERE command before. The command WHERE also works in bash, and it gives more information that WHICH. And you are right, they point to different places! I'll try changing the path variable to see if GITK and GITGUI pick up the new version as well.

Comment: Changing the path and the shortcuts did the trick!